# How to redirect to wiki page in edit mode on button click in SharePoint?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a button on the click of which I want it to redirect to wiki page of xyz in edit mode from its wiki page. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you open Developer Tools you'll see that the Edit button calls this javascript function:

```
 CoreInvoke("PageActionClick", this);
```

So when user redirect to `xyz` page at that time on Page Load, you need to be call the function somehow, but the second parameter cannot be "this" anymore, it needs to send the edit button object as reference.

#### javascript :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        CoreInvoke("PageActionClick", $("ctl00_PageStateActionButton"));
     });
```

Read for more details : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/c730ff5f-0ac0-4949-b712-f5e437f23311/

Comment: I want to use C# for doing this. In a way I want to use   Page.Response.Redirect("");

Comment: have you try like this : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30629/url-to-wiki-page-in-edit-mode. ??